# The preLaunchTask 'helloworld' terminated with exit code 1

Tags: c, json, windows, visual-studio-code

when i'm compiling my c file i'm getting the error

(/""Executing task: g++ -g helloworld.c <

'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.""/)

my launch.json file is

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [

    {
        "name": "(gdb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": " C:/wamp/www/ShareIdea/helloworld.c/hello.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": true,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\mingw-w64\\i686-7.2.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1\\mingw32\bin\\gdb.exe",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "helloworld"
    }



]
}
```

And my "tasks.json" file is

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "helloworld",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "g++",
        "args": [
            "-g",
            "helloworld.c"
        ]
        }

]
}
```

and i have edited c_cpp_properties.json as

```
       {
  "configurations": [
      {
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}",
            "C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-7.2.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/include/c++/tr1",
            "C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-7.2.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/include/c++",
            "C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-7.2.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/include"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE"
        ],
        "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64",
        "browse": {
            "path": [
                "${workspaceRoot}",
                "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\mingw-w64\\i686-7.2.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1\\mingw32\\lib\\gcc\\i686-w64-mingw32\\7.2.0\\include\\c++",
                "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\mingw-w64\\i686-7.2.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1\\mingw32\\lib\\gcc\\i686-w64-mingw32\\7.2.0\\include\\ssp\\stdio",
                "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\mingw-w64\\i686-7.2.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1\\mingw32\\i686-w64-mingw32\\include"
            ],
            "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
            "databaseFilename": ""
        }
    }
],
"version": 3
 }
```

Comment: not sure why this is tagged `c` but \, my guess you need to use the full-path to g++ as it is probably noy\t part of the PATH for the running environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have moved mingw-64 file from "C:\Program Files (x86)" to 'Desktop' and i have specified the full path in tasks.json(i.e.,("command":C:\Users\varunteja\Desktop\mingw-w64\i686-7.2.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1\mingw32\bin\g++",) instead of ("command": "g++",)).

And also i have edited "Launch.json" file.
In Launch.json file i have edited( "program": " C:/wamp/www/ShareIdea/helloworld.c/hello.exe",) as ( "program": " C:/wamp/www/ShareIdea/a.exe",) where a.exe file was created when i start debugging.

And also i have altered cwd  as ("cwd": " C:/wamp/www/ShareIdea",) which was the working directory of the target